# creating OpenActivity using Apex

Tags: apex, activities, read-only

I am trying to create OpenActivity using apex here is my snippet,

```
OpenActivity obj = new OpenActivity();
obj.DataDoctor7__Description__c = 'Hard Coding';
obj.DataDoctor7__Created_at__c = '29/01/2015';
insert obj;
```

when executed then i am getting error as 
Field is not writeable: `OpenActivity.DataDoctor7__Description__c`
where `DataDoctor7__Description__c` is my Activity custom field.
I have gone through the link below, 
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_openactivity.htm#topic-title

which says that openActivity is Read-Only. so can i create OpenActivity from apex.

Answer (score 1):

Activity is a special object. Activity contains Task and events. Events have a Start Date Time and End Date time.

Open activities are all that isClose is false. You can control open and close activities with the Status field in Task and Event Object.

I think that you want create a Task then your should create a Task Object.

```
Task testTask = new Task(
    DataDoctor7__Description__c = 'Hard Coding',
    DataDoctor7__Created_at__c  = Date.today()
);

insert testTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new Task (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm?SearchType=Stem) rather than an OpenActivity. You can set the Status to an open value which will create your OpenActivity record.

In order to associate the Task to a Contact set the WhoId to the Contact records Id.

Comment: @Torsen  what i need to do if want to show this task on particular contact eg: mahesh kajale is contact name

Comment: In order to associate the Task to a Contact set the WhoId to the Contact records Id.

Comment: @ForceHero is right, if you want associate the task to a Contact or a Lead you need use Who Id, if you want associate the task with Account, Opportunity or Custom Object you need use WhatId